# Convergence of backtracking and gradient descent.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am thinking a bit about the following exercise:

Let $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$ with **dom** $f = \{ (x_1,x_2):x_1 > 0 \}$. The optimal value of this problem is $p^* =1$, but it is never attained since $(1,0) \notin $ **dom** $f$.

Let $S = \{ (x_1,x_2) : f(x_1,x_2) \leq 4 \}$ be a sub-level set (which is not closed) and let $x^{0} = (2,2)$ be the starting point for gradient descent with backtracking line search.

The question is whether this will converge to $p^*$.

Attempt for solution:

Let $S_\epsilon = S \cap \{(x_1,x_2) : x_1 \geq1+\epsilon \} $, which is a closed convex set and contains $x^0$. Optimizing over this with back-tracking line search and gradient descent will give the optimal solution (1+epsilon,0) and $p^*_\epsilon = (1+\epsilon)^2$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we can get arbitrary close to $p^*$, so the optimization will converge.

Is this correct or have I missed something? :)

Comment: Why force yourself to use the wrong algorithm? Projected gradient descent is the standard choice for a case like this.

Comment: :) This is from the book Convex Optimization (9.3) and the question is what happens if you use gradient descent and backtracking line search, it is given in the exercise. Since the sub level set must be closed in general for this method to work we cannot be sure that it works. However, I don't see why we would not get arbitrarily close to the optimal value.